# The new Google Invisible reCaptcha - invisible or not?

Tags: recaptcha, invisible

Google announced Invisible ReCAPTCHA is coming soon. For now, if you want to integrate the new reCAPTCHA to your site or app you can [register here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/comingsoon/invisible.html).

I do have 2 site keys whitelisted for the new Invisible reCaptcha and I've started "playing" with their examples: see them here https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible

Yes, when the page loads the recaptcha is invisible but  when the form is submitted the recaptcha challenge appears all the time. You have to click on images, draw something around something else... etc

I've been testing this on different servers, 2 different sites which have the site key approved to use the Invisible reCaptcha, with different browsers form different locations. Same behavior: Google shows the challenge when the form is submitted on all 3 examples they have on their page.

Is this what we should expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as with the checkbox, if it can't reliably determine if you aren't a bot, you get a challenge. I can confirm that the invisible part does work when you are detected as a human.

Comment: Even when completing the challenge and redoing it again, it will ask for a challenge. Seems to me like it is broken at the moment.

Comment: You might try logging into your Google account, then going to your site with the captcha. Being logged into Google is a primary metric. If you're not logged in, you will almost always get a challenge. That is just how it is with the nocaptcha checkbox as well. It's blind to the past for the most part.

Comment: I can confirm, the robot part does work when you are not a human.

Comment: I have found this out the hard way. I was, falsely, under the impression that the rules to display the challenge were improved meaning it wasn't al about being signed in with a Google account, logged in on Chrome etc...Sure it saves a click, but it's not as ground-breaking as I originally thought.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to approve the Terms of Service when you create a new reCAPTCHA site, that says that

> You agree to explicitly inform visitors to your site that you have implemented the Invisible reCAPTCHA on your site and that their use of the Invisible reCAPTCHA is subject to the Google Privacy Policy and Terms of Use.